# Not found object error when importing external library in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Here is my sbt file `myproject/build.sbt`

```
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.16",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.6.1",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.6.1",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.6.1"
)
```

Here is my scala file `myproject/src/test.scala`

```
package mytest
import akka._
object test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      print(2)
    }
}
```

I verified that my external library contains, akka

but intellij keep saying that

```
Error:(7, 8) not found: object akka
import akka._
```

I am using `intellij community edition 2016.3` with the latest scala plugin (which should include latest sbt)

Can someone give me a hint on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you synchronized the project with SBT?

Comment: @adamwy I thought it automatically synchronized, but after you mentioned it I right click on `build.sbt` and click synchronized and rebuild the project, the same error still occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure if it synchronizes with SBT or just file system. I think the proper way to synchronize with SBT is to open `SBT projects` panel on the right and click on the refresh button.

Comment: @adamwy Yeah, I just did that too, but unfortunately I still run into the same problem

Comment: I've created same project as yours and it seems to work for me. It looks like `test.scala` should be placed in `src/main/scala` directory. Maybe that is causing the problem?

Comment: @adamwy it worked, thanks, do you want to answer the question below so that you can get recognized? Also another quick question, does every scala project have to be in `src/main/scala` ?

Comment: One thing that I realized was that when I was clicking "Recompile ..." it was giving me this error. And I tried "run" and it worked and when I hit "Recompile ..." again it compiled correctly this time!

Comment: I had same issue many times. The only thing that helped me to get rid of the problem was upgrading the IDEA to version 173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, you have to place your Scala source file into `src/main/scala` directory. Otherwise IntelliJ/SBT can't recognize it as file related to the project, so it can't associate project dependencies with it.

By default Scala source files can be placed either in the root directory of your project, or in `src/main/scala` (for main sources, there is also `src/test/scala` for tests).

If you want to use some other directories to store your Scala source files, you can configure it this way in your `build.sbt`:

```scala
sourceDirectories in Compile += new File("src")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it was nothing to do with the directory structure in my case. IntelliJ asks you to refresh when you add a new dependency in build.sbt. I also manually refreshed it form the SBT Shell and still same error.

In the end I closed the project and re-opened and it was fixed.